# Custom font not showing up in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I've followed all the steps in [Apple's tutorial to add custom fonts](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/text_display_and_fonts/adding_a_custom_font_to_your_app):

I've added the font files under a folder called `fonts`:

[image]

I've registered the fonts by adding them to `Info.plist`:

[image]

However Xcode cannot use them/find them:

```
Button(action: {}){
                Text("View profile")
                    .font(Font.custom("seravekBold.tff", size: 20.0))
```

I've also tried testing this method:

```
for family in UIFont.familyNames.sorted() {
    let names = UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: family)
    print("Family: \(family) Font names: \(names)")
}
```

in my `AppDelegate` to print out all the UI fonts and the fonts I added (`seravek`) do not show up.

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Check the Build Phases in the Copy Bundle Resources if it's in that list.

And as far as I know, there is no need to add the .tff in the Font.custom("").

Comment: Not sure what `Build Phases in the Copy Bundle Resources` is? And I tested without the `.ttf` and still doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: I've made a preview on how to find it. [here](https://imgur.com/a/XBXUPSN)

Comment: Thanks it is in that list: https://i.imgur.com/XXtUVVb.png But just noticed that the folder is not actually inside my project directory - it's on my desktop. Could this be the problem?

Comment: I've added the same font that you are using and used a custom font from a previous project. The other font is working but the seravek one is not. I'm not sure why but it seems like the font you want to use is not supported by iOS or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for testing. Very weird - i'll have to use another font.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is my steps (demo prepared & tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14):

1. taken font for demo from  http://fdempreendimentos.com.br/assets/fonts/Seravek-Bold.ttf
2. drag & drop into project & mark checkbox to include to app target

[image: demo]

3. Registered font with Info.plist

[image: demo2]

4. Demo content view

```
struct TestSeravekFont: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World! Specific Qij")
            .font(Font.custom("Seravek Bold", size: 40))
    }
}
```

5. Output

[image: demo3]

Here is how font looks in Font Manager, so we see that this is it. Done.

[image: demo4]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after make empty .xib file and put some labels with custom font,

SwiftUI's `.custom(font_name)` and `UIFont.familyNames` works well.

I thinks that there are some missing bundle for custom fonts with out UIKit Resources.

At iOS 14.5, Xcode 12.5.

Answer (score 0):

Apply bellow process

1. Drag and drop your font file, must include copy item if needed and target project.
2. Register your font in info.plist(must include extension .ttf or .otf)
3. Verify the Font Names: It’s important to verify the exact font names that SwiftUI expects. Open the custom font files in Font Book (on macOS) or Font Viewer (on Windows), and make a note of the PostScript name or the font family name.