# Why is my custom font not working in Xcode?

Tags: fonts, swiftui

So this problem is all over the internet, but I've completed the steps of nearly every listed successful solution and I want to make sure I ask with my specific case before I have to try reinstalling my macOS. I'm trying to use a custom font in my iOS app, Montserrat. The font file name is "Montserrat-Regular.ttf". I began by adding the file to my project, with the project selected as a target:

[image]

I also added it to my Info.plist file in "Fonts provided by application":

[image]

And it is in my Copy Bundle Resources:

[image]

Despite all this, when I try to use the font for a Text object in my SwiftUI app like so:

```
Text("Welcome Back!")
    .position(x: (geometry.size.width / 2), y: 160.0)
    .foregroundColor(.white)
    .font(Font.custom(Constants.FontStrings.montserratReg, size: 30.0))
```

I still get the default font. When I run a for loop to print out all the font families I have, interestingly, Montserrat doesn't show up:
[image]

Even though it is listed in my Font book. Actually several of the fonts in my Font book didn't show up here, I'm not sure if that's relevant:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/64049267/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi unfortunately no, these are all steps I've already taken

Comment: What is Constants.FontStrings.montserratReg?

Comment: @TamásSengel That's where I store the string for the font, I keep it in a Constants file to avoid errors

Comment: What is the value of it?

Comment: @TamásSengel "Montserrat-Regular"

Comment: Where does the font name 'montserratReg' come from?

Comment: The font name is not inside the "Fonts provided by the application" array.

Comment: @TamásSengel What do you mean? I have a screenshot of it in that array in my question.

Comment: @byfu34 It's not inside the array, it's next to it. You need to open the array and place the font name string *inside* it.

Comment: Wow I am a moron thank you so much.